# Use SCSS variable based on ancestor class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a switch between light and dark theme in my app.

My HTML looks something like this (simplified code):

```
<div class="root light">
  <div class="child">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

And my current SCSS is as follows:

```
.light {
  $custom-bg: lightgreen;
}

.dark {
  $custom-bg: darkgreen;
}

.child {
  background-color: $custom-bg;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lntody9)

The idea is to use the `custom-bg` variable in the children so whenever i want to change the theme, i only have to switch between `light` and `dark` classes on `root` and the children would automatically use the appropriate `background-color` value.

But this doesn't work. The `child` class does not see the `custom-bg` variable and i cannot figure out how to solve this.

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rearrange your scss to be like this

```
$custom-bg-dark: darkgreen;
$custom-bg-light: lightgreen;
.light.child{
 background-color:  $custom-bg-light;
}

.dark.child{
  background-color:  $custom-bg-dark;
}

.child {
  background-color: $custom-bg;
}
```